# ADO NET Entity Model not working when created inside app_code in webforms

Tags: c#, asp.net

im trying to upgrade to ADO.NET entity from DataSet tools cause they are outdated and I can't get it to work.

I have a BLL folder and a DAL folder in App_Code

```
Solution
- App_Code
  - EmployeeDS.cs
  - BLL
  - DAL
    - InventarioCiclicoDB.edmx
```

However when I try to do this

```
 using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using InventarioCiclico.App_Code.DAL;

namespace InventarioCiclico.App_Code
{
    public class EmployeeDS
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public string GetEmployees()
        {
            InventarioCiclicoEntities db = new InventarioCiclicoEntities();
            db.
        }
    }
}
```

nothing appears but a IfNotNull method... Why does this happen? If I create the entity model on the solution root directoy it works fine, but if i do it in DAL folder it doesn't

Comment: well edmx is also outdated like datasets :-)

Comment: what would you recommend then?

Comment: Either ef core or ef 6 .depending on your needs. see comparison here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/efcore-and-ef6/ (if you have to use ef 6 for some reasons, i would suggest to use code first without edmx)

Comment: I cant seem to find any EF6 tutorial for webforms. I found one but was basically the same thing i just posted here... using ADO net model

Comment: any reason not to use ef core?

Comment: I could look into it, i just picked EF6 since apps are for windows only

Comment: The future is ef core. As you can read from the page that i posted you it says "EF6 continues to be a supported product, and will continue to see bug fixes and minor improvements." Meaning there will not be major innovation in the future. All efforts are going into ef core.

Comment: You can find tutorials and sample apps here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/?view=aspnetcore-2.2 or https://github.com/dotnet-architecture/eShopOnWeb

Comment: This is aall for mvc or .net core, is this compatible with webforms?

Comment: Thanks, i think i will stick with EF6. I read core doesn't support stored procedures and I'm working with many of them in an ongoing project

Comment: yes it is compatible with webforms and it also works with stored procedures. see here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/raw-sql. however if stored procuderues dominates i don't see really many benefits of using entity framework. in that case i would rather use dapper i guess.